# Know data type of the list elements

Tags: c, data-structures

I have list of 5 elements. I get first element of this list. How can i kwno what's the data type of this element char* or int*?

Thank you

Comment: what type you are storing in the list ? it is of the same type. Or can you post some code showing how you are creating the list?

Comment: There is no standard list construct in C, thus you should expand on what construct you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Either use type-specific lists (one list for your char-pointers, one list for your ints) or use a structure or union to store both types of values with a field that indicates the type, like this:

```
#define TYPE_INT    1
#define TYPE_STRING 2

struct MyValue
{
int type;        // TYPE_INT or TYPE_STRING
union
   {
   char *str;
   int   i;
   } value;
};
```

And store this struct into your list.

If C++ is an option, consider using std::list to store type specific data, or if this is not possible, define a class similar to the struct above in which you shield the different data types, like this (not including error checking on the type):

```
class MyValue
   {
   public:
      enum ValueType
         {
         TYPE_NONE;
         TYPE_INT,
         TYPE_STRING
         };
      MyValue() : m_type(TYPE_NONE) {}
      MyValue(char *s) : m_type(TYPE_STRING), m_value.str(s) {}
      MyValue(int i) : m_type(TYPE_INT), m_value.int(i) {}
      ValueType getType() const {return m_type;}
      const char *getString() const {return m_value.str;}
      int getInt() const {return m_value.int;}
   private:
      ValueType m_type;
      union InternalValue
         {
         char *str;
         int   i;
         };
      InternalValue m_value;
   };
```

Comment: Why not `enum` instead of `#define`?

Comment: @Georg, this is because in my old C days, we couldn't use enums, only defines.  I agree, enums are better.

Answer (score 1):

In C, there is no (portable) way to find out if all you have is a void*. So you have to keep track about it yourself, when you store the elements into the list. Another possibility is to use type-specific lists instead of a generic void* list.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "list" here?

Is it:

```
   sometype* lst;
```

i.e. an array, or:

```
node* lst;
```

A linked list?

In the first case, `sometype` defines the type of elements in the array, unless it's some kind of a `void*` which means that the compiler doesn't know the type but the programmer (hopefully) does. In the second case you should look into the definition of `node`, it should contain data with typing information of some sort (and the `void*` argument from above applies).